# How to approach a real machine learning problem?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study

As a ML beginner, I don't how to begin with this problem, or more generally, are there any typical steps to take when approaching a real problem?

If I have some domain relevant knowledge, then I could make use of it to analyze the data and do the modelling. But if I don't, then all I have is just the data, a matrix of input and a vector of response (if supervised).

My question is if I don't have domain knowledge, what to do before I randomly try out some learning algorithms and tune the parameters? Am I supposed to analyze the data per se to find out any clue and how?

Answer (score 2):

Some Exploratory Data Analysis can help you to get some hints about the data you're dealing with. 
See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_data_analysis
Or, for some exploratory data analysis techniques, take a look: https://www.coursera.org/course/exdata

Comment: Thanks, I read some about EDA, so before modeling, doing some EDA which might give us some insights about the data, which might be useful to come up with the right model, right?

Comment: Exactly, it gives you an idea of how the data is structured and, by that, it can show you if a given model would be relevant.